# How to get the same color for the boundary and the shading in ListContourPlot?

Tags: plotting, color

If I specify the ContourShading to be the same color as the Contour they end up being a different color, see the example below.

```
ListContourPlot[
 Table[{i, j, Boole[i + j > 5]}, {i, 0, 10}, {j, 0, 10}] // 
  Flatten[#, {1, 2}] &
 , Contours -> {0.5}
 , ContourStyle -> Directive[ColorData[97][1], AbsoluteThickness[8]]
 , ContourShading -> {None, ColorData[97][1]}
 ]
```

How can I make them the same color?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mathematica uses `Opacity[0.5]` that can be seen with `InputForm` of your graphics. So add `Opacity[1]` to `ContourStyle` option:

```
ListContourPlot[
Table[{i, j, Boole[i + j > 5]}, {i, 0, 10}, {j, 0, 10}] // 
Flatten[#, {1, 2}] &, Contours -> {0.5}, 
ContourStyle -> 
Directive[ColorData[97][1], AbsoluteThickness[8], Opacity[1]], 
ContourShading -> {None, ColorData[97][1]}]
```

[image]